# Is it possible to read nfc Uid to linux browser?

Tags: linux, nfc, uniqueidentifier

We are trying to develop this simple web app with my friends. We would need a little bump to right direction. The program itself would be written in html with some php and JavaScript in it. It would be driven in localhost environment. We have a NFC reader for our computer already. We would need to read uid from nfc tag and write it to html form. Is it possible and with what language we should do it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and you should look for a sdk for your NFC reader and then use one of the languages the reader supports.

You find a linux sdk here:

http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U

It is written in c, so unless you find another one: use c ;)

Comment: The reader is ACR122U and i cant seem to find an sdk for it. Well I did but it was only for windows...

Comment: look above :) i added a link

Comment: Thank you. Have to start studing c then. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try [pcsc-tools](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/) package on Linux. It has pcsc_scan utility which show's you UID when you putting card in field range of NFC reader.